# Cannot click mouse while moving in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, keyboard, mouse

In Java Minecraft 1.16.5 I cannot left click my mouse while moving. I am running Dell Inspiron 7746 and Windows 10. I already changed touchpad sensitivity to most sensitive as suggested in many posts. I also learned that reassigning mouse left click to keyboard helps, but I do not like this solution. I also tried disabling touchpad without any luck. I also reinstalled Minecraft. Funny enough I have Windows Minecraft edition on the same computer and it works fine.

What else can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Is the issue occuring with a mouse, your touchpad, or both?

Comment: @hyper-neutrino, I have not tried touchpad yet, but it definitely occurs with the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience this was caused by the Synaptics touchpad software. Try the following:

1. Open mouse properties (open Run with windows key + R and type 'control mouse' without quotations)
2. Open the 'Clickpad' tab and then click on Values
3. Click on Advanced and then on SmartSense/Palm Check.
4. Set it to the minimum (or 'Off' if the option is available)